# SET MAX NUMBER of Magnitude?

Tags: ios

I have been working with this project for a while:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/teslameter/Introduction/Intro.html

and I am trying to figure out how to make highest the numbers go up to as 100. So if it were to go to 101 it would show as 100, how would I go about doing that? I have tried things such as

```
if (magnitudeLabel.text >= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", 99])
{
    setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",100];    
}
```

but nothing works and it goes over 100.

Comment: `>=` with `NSString` ?
`if ([[magnitudeLabel text] intValue] > YourMaxmimumValue)` should be better.

Comment: As the answer itself has already been pointed out I won't add to that, I thought I'd just point out that when you're using stringWithFormat, '%f' is to format a float or double. You'll get a compiler warning for using an integer there like you are. You should use '%d' instead - which also means you don't have to define the decimal places with the '%.0' bit. -> [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 99]

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([magnitudeLabel.text intValue] > 100) {
    [magnitudeLabel setText:@"100"];
}
```

Seems fair enough, right?

Comment: I have tried 'if ([magnitudeLabel.text intValue] > 100) {
    [magnitudeLabel setText:@"100"];
}' but it still goes above 100. any other ideas?

Comment: Just for it to work! Thank you very much! Apparently I had something causing a conflict.